Adding event listener to a DynamicForm field
I have a form customizer project that uses typescript and react.
I have a choice field which renders as a dropdown and one of the choices is to leave a comment.
If the user selects the 'leave a comment' choice I wan to show a multiline text field beneath the dropdown that allows the user to enter their comment.
This would be a very simple task in straight javascript. Just changing the visibility style of the textbox within the onchange event of the dropdown, but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this task in the form customizer project.
Does anyone have an example of how to do this or any other information that would be helpful?
Thanks!

In SPFx I would work with fluent ui components and a react FunctionComponent. For example with a Dropdown control and a TextField. Then it would just be some basic "React" code.
You have the components and on the onChange-Event you set a boolean variable to true, when the relevant key is selected ("1" in my case). When the variable "showCommentBox" is true, then the TextField for the comments is rendered.
<Dropdown 
  label={"My Dropdown"}
  disabled={false}
  onChange={(_e, option) => {
    //when the relevant key is selected
    if(option && option.key === "1") {
      //set the state of "showCommentBox" to true
      setShowCommentBox(true);
    }
  }}
  options={[
    {
      key: "1",
      text: "Leave a comment"
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      text: "Value 2"
    }
  ]} />
  {
    showCommentBox &&
    <TextField label={"Comments"} multiline/>
  }

Somewhere at the beginning of the component you would have the boolean variable
const [showCommentBox, setShowCommentBox] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

